# How to pass args passed to an event to the error block with aasm?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, state-machine, aasm

My event is defined this way:

```
event :share, after: :inc_in_path_share do
      transitions from: :bucketed, to: :shared
      error do |e|
        inc_share(message, tags)
      end
    end
```

and I call it `my_instance.share(message, tags)`. If the transition is allowed, I don't have problem to call `inc_in_path_share` with `message` and `tags`. But when the transition is not allowed, I want to have a default action processed by `inc_share` in my `error` block.

How to pass message and tags to the `error` block ? May be the way I am thinking it is not the best too (XY problem). Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan Pares created a ticket for this on AASM's github page (see https://github.com/aasm/aasm/issues/196). I (maintainer of AASM) will implement this feature.